# List all MongoDB Databases and their details from Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am developing a Java/MongoDB application and require a list of all existing MongoDB Databases.

I know I can use this code:-

```
final MongoClient mongoClient = DatabaseManager.getMongoclient();

final ListDatabasesIterable<Document> databasesDocument = mongoClient.listDatabases();
final MongoCursor<Document> mongoCursor = databasesDocument.iterator();

while (mongoCursor.hasNext()) {
    final Document databaseDocument = mongoCursor.next();
    Assert.assertNotNull(databaseDocument);
}
```

However the details only include the Database Name, its size on disk, and whether or not the database is empty.

I need to know when the database was created, `when = Date & Time`.

Is there anyway I can retrieve this information from within a Java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, MongoDB doesn't keep track of database creation dates.

One possible workaround if you are creator of databases is tracking it  by yourself. Create `meta collection` in `meta database` and insert new record `db_name=time` when you create database.

Comment: Thanks, i was getting round to thinking this was my only solution